# <table> becomes empty, when I'm trying to get it via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to parse a table from website `https://www.kp.ru/best/kazan/abiturient_2018/ivmit/`. DevTools by Chrome shows me that table is:

```
<div class="t431__table-wapper" data-auto-correct-mobile-width="false"> 
<table class="t431__table " style="">
...
</table>
</div>
```

But when I do this:

```
url = r"https://www.kp.ru/best/kazan/abiturient_2018/ivmit/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find_all('div', {'class':r't431__table-wapper'})
print(tag)
```

It returns me like `<table>` is empty:

```
[<div class="t431__table-wapper" data-auto-correct-mobile-width="false">
<table class="t431__table" style=""></table></div>, 
<div class="t431__table-wapper" data-auto-correct-mobile-width="false">
<table class="t431__table" style=""></table></div>,
<div class="t431__table-wapper" data-auto-correct-mobile-width="false">
<table class="t431__table" style=""></table></div>,
<div class="t431__table-wapper" data-auto-correct-mobile-width="false">
<table class="t431__table" style=""></table></div>]
```

Is it JavaScript or something? How to fix this?

Comment: Visiti the site. If it loads data via javascript you need to wailt till the whole page is loaded before you can find the table data you seek for. Beautiful soup can not do this. Try some full fledged browser emulator - f.e. Selenium and wait till the whole page is loaded before scraping.

Comment: [beautifulsoup-unable-to-recognize-values-from-a-particular-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314004/beautifulsoup-unable-to-recognize-values-from-a-particular-table#comment97355386_55314004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that info from another tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.kp.ru/best/kazan/abiturient_2018/ivmit/'
soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.t431__data-part2').text)
```

Output:

[image]